# CodeIgniter - Form validation set false

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have some script for image upload and I'm using it with form validation. So this is the code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','required|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('desc','Description','required|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
{
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
        'upload_path' => path/to/folder,
        'max_size' => 3000,
        'max_height' => 1024,
        'max_width' => 1024,
        'remove_spaces' => TRUE
    );
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        //code for insert this data into database
    }
    else
    {
        //code for FALSE the form validation and error message with flashdata
    }
```

Now I would like to false form if there is some error with image upload. I want to do this like the error of some field (if it's empty), to get data of post variables back (for field's content).

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` condition of the `$this->form_validation->run()` and `$this->upload->do_upload()` should be similiar.

form validation:

```
$data['error_message'] = validation_errors();
$this->load->view('form', $data);
```

file upload:

```
$data['error_message'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
$this->load->view('form', $data);
```

The 'form' view is the one loaded initially. It can have a div of this sort:

```
<div class="error_message">
   <?php if ($error_message) {
      echo $error_message;
   } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that, but I'm not asking this. I'm looking for solution which will only false execution of form validation if there something isn't good with uploading file.

Example:
    `if ($uploaderror == TRUE)
     {
        return false; //false form validation and get all values of fields back
     }`

Comment: Loading the form again like I mentioned in the reply should do just that. If you want to repopulate the fields, simply use the `set_value` function on each of the fields. The `else` condition of `if ($this->upload->do_upload())` serves exactly as `if ($uploaderror == TRUE)`

Comment: Your answer is right and the problem was on my side. I'm using little different set_value and I don't think on it. Thanks again.

Comment: Just one question more... Is it possible to get some function like set_value for form_upload() because if there's error with form's field, this path disappears?

Comment: You cannot save the path of the image on the user's computer for security reasons. However, you can perform the upload before the validation of the entire form, like this: `if ($this->upload->do_upload() && $this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)` or you can do that in a callback function of the form validation. Read more: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/150397/#729889

Comment: This `if ($this->upload->do_upload() && $this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)` doesn't work properly if there's error at form validation. If I change order of form validation and upload is the same as before with code in my first post.

Comment: Nevermind, I used validation_errors() and if there is any validation error, the image already saves into directory and then shows at form error, so there is no again upload needed.